# 301 redirects for lots of pages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have inherited a site that was built with Joomla and the migrated to WordPress. There are 500 posts with the same name, but the path before the name of the post is different. How can I write in htaccess a rule that chceck if the name of the post is identical then it redirects to the new path+name of post without having to write 500 "301 redirects"?

All old pages have been indexed and they give 404 errors. They posts have been imported from Joomla to Wordpress with a plugin and they all exists in the new website.

**Old website:**

```
http://vitalpethealth.co.uk/index.php/dogs/dog-section-layout/dog-behaviour-and-training/447-separation-anxiety-of-our-dogs
```

**New website:**

```
http://vitalpethealth.co.uk/separation-anxiety-of-our-dogs/
```

Any pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: Do these pages have the exact same content and is this for SEO purposes?

Comment: Yes, they have the same content

Comment: Are you doing this because you're worried about the impact that duplicate content might have on your SEO?

Comment: Yes. All old pages have been indexed and give 404 errors (more than 500 to be precise)..

Comment: Ok, so how many of them still exist or are they all gone now?

Comment: All of them exist. The previous developer used some plugin to import Joomla posts into WordPress.

Comment: You could use the canonical link tag. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en and point it to the main URL that you want indexed.

Comment: From a database a PHP code can read off the redirects that redirect you to the new pages.